# moving text below image with css only

Tags: html, css

I am using a widget on my site that I do not have access to the main code.

However I can style it to my liking with css. I am trying to move the text below the image but I can't seem to get it.

here is the html:

```
<div class="dd-widget dd-box dd-top-fundraisers dd-widget-complete" data-type="topFundraisers" data-event-id="503">
    <h1> Top Fundraisers</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="dd-avatar-link" href=""><img src="img.jpg" scale="0"><span class="tf-full-name">person name</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dd-avatar-link" href=""><img src="img.jpg" scale="0"><span class="tf-full-name">person name</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="dd-avatar-link" href=""><img src="img.jpg" scale="0"><span class="tf-full-name">person name</span></a></li>
        <a class="dd-view-more-link btn" href=""> View More</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have added my own css to the list to make it display inline. as I want the images to display horizontally. Now however the span class with the person name is displayed next to the image.

```
div.dd-widget li {display:inline;}
```

My goal is to have it underneath the image. I was trying to experiment with adding a line space through css but don't think that is the right way to go about it.

Comment: The HTML is invalid anyway...an `a` tag cannot be a direct child of a `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>` tag is by default `inline`, as is `<img>`. However, by making your images `display: block;` they will occupy the full width of ur list items, making ur `<span>` tags jump down.

This is achieved with:

```
div.dd-widget li img {
   display: block;
}
```

As pointed out by AndrewTet, this will make your list items appear under each other. To fix this simply set their `display` attribute to `inline-block`:

```
div.dd-widget li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hey @piers, this actually doesn't quite work as you can see here: http://codepen.io/supah_frank/pen/jEEzbv. Adding the block element to the img does push the text down to the next line, but it also forces the lis down to the next line. You need to add something like `div.dd-widget li {display:inline-block;}` so changing the img to `display: block` doesn't force the lis down a line.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css to this.

```
div.dd-widget li {display:inline-block;}
div.dd-widget img {display:block;}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/supah_frank/pen/VYYXLK

Comment: Nice one, don't forget your vertical align! ;)

Comment: I left the vertical align off because the code in the original post  doesn't specify where it is supposed to be aligned. To avoid confusion, I figured I give the most basic answer possible and let @Sackling take it from there. You are correct though, in use, a vertical align will probably be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Super basic solution:

CSS (make more specific as you need):

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

li img {
    display: block;
}
```

This allows your <li> tags to flow horizontally, while the img contained within will display as block, causing any following elements to flow below on the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Update your CSS with this one.**

```
div.dd-widget li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
div.dd-widget li img{
    display: block;
}
```

This will move the text below image with images displayed horizontally.
Here is the JSFiddle link. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/z5vp0spt/)**